# Can we access a private variable in another class in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
class Animal {
    private name:string;
    public Firstname:string;
    constructor(theName: string)
    {
        this.name = theName;
        this.Firstname=theName;
    }
}

class Tiger {
    function sample(){
        Animal animalName=new Animal('Tiger');
        document.body.innerHTML = animalName.name;
    }
    sample();
}
```

Hi am new to this TypeScript here in animal class I've created a private variable name I used that in class constructor. Now in class `Tiger` I created the instance for `Animal` class and able to access that private variable.

My question is in Java if we do we will get error. But in TypeScript (because TypeScript supports OOPS) we are not getting any error moreover it is giving the value how is it possible?

Comment: @JamesWilkins That's talking about `readonly` not `private`.

Comment: Right, thanks for catching that @Timmmm. ;)

Answer (score 42):

First - your code will not compile. TypeScript will check the accessibility of the name and give you an error. Check yourself at typescript playground: [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground)

Second - it is possible access private properties if you will remove typescript checks, for example:

```
console.log((<any>animalName).name)
```

This works due to the fact that natively JavaScript does not have a notion of private properties. And as TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript you have such a possibility.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Would like to mention that relying on the fact the `private` isn't private at runtime would make code migration harder at some point + highly decrease maintainability. OP should please rethink their design.

Answer (score 30):

An alternative to using the `as any` trick that Amid posted is to use the string index notation, which is an [intentional escape hatch](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19335) for accessing private members:

```js
console.log(animalName['name']);
```

This has the advantage of being type-safe, so if you ever remove `name`, you'll get a compiler error here.

Comment: If you're using eslint's `dot-notation` rule, you might get a warning. Consider adopting a convention of having all private members start with an underscore; that way, you could update your eslint config to have `'dot-notation': ['error', {allowPattern: '^_'}],` to ignore such fields.

Answer (score -1):

Directly it is not possible to access private variable from another class, but it can be achieved through getter and setter methods.

Comment: As written in the other answers: It is possible, because [tag:javascript] has no access modifier.