# Accessing a private constructor

Tags: typescript, private-constructor

I have a Typescript class with a private constructor:

```
class Foo {
  private constructor(private x: number) {}
}
```

For testing purposes I would like to call this constructor from outside the class (please don't argue this point). Typescript provides an escape method for accessing private fields, like `foo["x"]` (see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626400/can-we-access-a-private-variable-in-another-class-in-typescript/35627905)) but I can't figure out the syntax for calling the constructor. It should be something like this right?

```
const f = new Foo["constructor"](5);
```

But that doesn't work. What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could assert `Foo` as `any`:

```
class Foo {
    private constructor(private x: number) {}
}

const instance = new (Foo as any)(5) as Foo;
console.log(instance);
```

But perhaps you might just want to create a static method that constructs an instance with a clear name that it's for testing:

```
class Foo {
    private constructor(private x: number) {}

    /** @internal */
    static createForTesting(x: number) {
        return new Foo(x);
    }
}

const instance = Foo.createForTesting(5);
```

Note: The `/** @internal */` excludes the method declaration from appearing in declaration files.

Comment: Ah nice, that works. Out of curiosity is there a way to do it with `["constructor"]`? Seems like there should be since you can use that method for other properties.

Comment: "Out of curiosity is there a way to do it with `["constructor"]`"?  No, `Foo` *is* the constructor you want.  The `constructor` property of `Foo` would be *its* constructor, presumably `Function`.